# What kind of cover do I need for a sectional to protect my furniture from my cat's claws?

Tags: cats, containment, furniture

We recently bought a sectional couch with a short chaise extension and back (picture included), and initially we were using a loveseat and sofa cover to protect the new furniture from our cat's claws (Declawing is *not* an option for us).

We want to get a cover to protect the other half of our couch, but we're not sure what kind we need - what do we need to protect this part of our sectional from cat claws?

[image]

Comment: What claw-action do you worrie about? intentional sratching, or "only" wandering over the couch?

Comment: @Allerleirauh Intentional scratching, especially the "I'm going to scratch this edge of the couch before I hop up on it" scratching, which is what our cats tend to do.

Comment: Does your cat have a scratching post in this room? Or anywhere else in the house?

Comment: A cloth cover might not protect your couch from scratching. If their claws can get through the material, they will scratch the sofa through it.

Comment: U shouldn't have to Worry about ur cat clawing at ur furniture its,ridiculous, they do have a scratching post, but they intend to claw,at other things to for some reason. Will have my cats declawed soon.

Comment: @TabathaFesta declawing is unnecessary cruelty. If your couch is more important to you than your cat's long-term health, please rehome your cat.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing is immune to cat claws (except maybe actual rock, but that doesn’t make for nice couch cushions). Instead, **provide your cat with plenty of other things to scratch in the same room**. Different cats love different methods of scratching, so it may take some observing and trial/error to find out what your cat likes best.

I’ve had a lot success with corrugated [cardboard scratchers](https://www.chewy.com/all-kind-double-cat-scratcher-toy/dp/201490?utm_source=google-product&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=hg&utm_content=All%20Kind&utm_term=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8Z269pqu7AIVVR6tBh3O8wLtEAQYASABEgJo4_D_BwE). They’re inexpensive, last a good while, and can be recycled when spent. A lot of them come with catnip as a scent incentive. Place them where your cat spends the most time. Easy access is key!

Vertical scratch poles, usually with thick rope or carpet, are also great options. This would be a great option as part of a cat perch. Placing it next to your couch will help encourage the cat to use the perch (and thus the scratch post) instead of your couch.

You may also find that there are certain fabrics the cat likes or doesn’t like. It’s never guaranteed of course, but the more texture a fabric has, the more of a claw magnet it is (think rough tree bark vs a plastic fence post).

Comment: This is good advice - I do already have several cardboard scratchers though, and a cat tower.

Answer (score 3):

You might wish to try a DIY-type solution using **basic "percale" style bedsheets**. These are the bog-standard style of smooth, tightly-woven fabric; very easy to get, and, conveniently, a texture cats don't typically care to claw on. Depending on the size and construction of your pieces, you may be able to purchase fitted sheets that can be wrapped around the base of your sectional fairly easily, with minimal to no sewing required. Similarly, you may be able to tuck an appropriately sized flat sheet fairly securely into place and do minimal to no modification to secure it from slipping, again with little to no sewing.

Basic smooth/slick fitted sheets are a common fix for shredded box springs, which tend to be something cats particularly enjoy scratching on and burrowing into; a cheap sheet secured around the bottom of a box spring, or anything similar you don't want them scratching, is an effective and inexpensive way to bring an end to the behavior.